# SSH -X "Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated"

Tags: ssh, xorg, xserver

Hey I'm having an issue getting ssh X forwarding to work. The setup is I'm `ssh`ing into my ubuntu VM off OSX Yosemite host machine.

I already installed xQuartz on OSX, xauth on ubuntu, and I believe I've have all the correct options set in ssh_config files.

I get the

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

message when opening a connection with `ssh -X`, and when I tried to run an X application:

```
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

I have the identical setup on my other machine except running Mavericks and it works fine, is there something specific to Yosemite specific I have to worry about?

Answer (score 90):

Note that some incomplete answers might lead to security flaws.

1. Using ssh -Y means here having fake xauth information which is bad!
2. ssh -X should work since XQuartz, once enabled, uses xauth. The only problem is that ssh is looking for xauth in `/usr/X11R6/bin` and on macOS with XQuartz it is in /opt/X11/bin

**Secure** solution:

1. Enable the first option in the *Security* tab of preferences (Cmd-,) which enables authenticated connections.
2. Edit `~/.ssh/config`, add `XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth` to the host config.
3. `ssh -X your_server` works in a secure manner.
4. Ensure xauth is installed on the destination host.

Comment: @TobySpeight This answer solved my OSX->Linux login problem. As far as I am concerned it was very helpful. Upvoted.

Comment: This fixed my X forwarding after it was broken by upgrade to OSX High Sierra

Comment: Does not work on OSX Mojave, but @XValidated's answer below successfully connects, though a warning about missing xauth data is shown.

Comment: I tried this on Mojave and it made `ssh -X ...` just hang.

Comment: After upgrading to Mojave I was getting the error in the OP. This fixed the issue.

Comment: adding "XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth" into my .ssh/config fixed my issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 60):

On macOS Sierra, I now have to do `ssh -Y` instead of `ssh -X` to get a display from a linux machine to work on my Mac.

Comment: This may solve the issue, but it also enables trusted forwarding instead of the more secure trusted one. @Koko's answer fixed it for me without having to use "-Y" instead of "-X" which is preferable.

Answer (score 42):

I received the same warning as you after upgrading to Yosemite.
After I added `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in my `~/.ssh/config` file, the warning disappeared.

Do you have the following lines in your `~/.ssh/config` file for enabling Trusted X11 forwarding?

```
Host APPROPRIATE_HOSTNAME
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    OTHER_OPTIONS
```

Comment: Good to hear someone got it working. Which side of the ssh are you talking about? I have that in my ~/.ssh/config on ubuntu.

Comment: I no longer get the warning, but I still get X11 `forwarding request failed on channel 0`

Comment: the ssh settings should be adjusted on the "client" side, i.e. your Mac machine because you are trying to ssh from your Mac to use the host ubuntu VM machine. (and why do you want to ssh to a ubuntu VM?)

Comment: Works for macOS High Sierra

Comment: I'm getting same warning in Redhat and changing the config file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` did the trick. Thankyou

Comment: @sprw121 For `X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0` in my case, I did a `yum install xauth` on the remote server, then that particular message went away...and was replaced with `connect /tmp/.X11-unix/X0: No such file or directory` which meant this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429812/8337

Comment: Works on OSX Mojave, though a warning about missing xauth data is shown (for some machines but not for all; not sure why).

Answer (score 13):

Gilles Gouaillardet has the answer that solved this for me. Edit **~/.ssh/config** to contain

```
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

and ssh -X hostname now works (XQuartz 2.7.11, macOS 10.4 Mojave)

Comment: xauth is needed on destination host too by the way

Answer (score 7):

I already had the latest XQuartz 2.7.11 installed, but I think I've also updated the OS a few times since then.  I reinstalled XQuartz 2.7.11, and now it is working fine.

Comment: Good find - reinstalling the same (latest) version of XQuartz worked for me too

Comment: I also had to do this; I hadn't tried to use X forwarding since upgrading macOS, and although XQuartz would start up fine, forwarding wouldn't work. This worked when none of the other answers did.

Answer (score 1):

ForwardX11Trusted is required even for connections you think are untrusted when your X server doesn't have the SECURITY extension (Apple servers have a ton of visuals that take up over 100 lines, so I suggest "xdpyinfo | grep SECURITY" to check; if that returns no output, you don't have it).  There may be other reasons and exceptions, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the latest X11 version and it worked again

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this issue using Mac OS X 10.6.8 to Linux Debian 9.
None of the solutions provided worked.

Root cause was: loopback interface was "DOWN" on the target Linux host.

I had to type the following on the target host to fix the issue

`ip link set lo up`

Answer (score 0):

Same as answered by user Xvalidated above. but there was no ssh_config file in my .ssh directory.
1. copy ./etc/ssh_config  to ~/.ssh/ #file if not there
2. edit 
Host hostname
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  ForwardX11 yes

2. As answered before, I would like to add one more thing which will work to reinstall X-supporting software.

Answer (score -4):

When you login the cluster, do not use -X or -Y options.

Example:

```
ssh -Y remotelogin: gives me X11 related warning.
```

ssh remotelogin: No warning, works fine.

Comment: `-X` is not always neccessary

Comment: So...if you don't need remote X, then don't use `-X`, got it :)